# Length of the segments of the side of a triangle divided by the inradius of an inscribed circle

Tags: geometry, contest-math

A circle is inscribed in a triangle whose sides are $9$ cm, $14$ cm and $17$ cm. If $P$
separates the $14$ – cm side into segments whose ratio is $x : y$ with $x < y$,
find the values of $x$ and $y$.
[image]
I think that I'm supposed to be finding the inradius of the circle inscribed, but I don't know how to approach the question afterwards. Is there a way to find similar triangles using the point $P$?

Comment: How P is defined? Tangent point on that side?

Comment: @Moti ah right, i forgot to add a photo

Comment: The drawing has an error - 9 replaced by 14.

Answer (score 2):

See the following figure:[image]

You can easily compare this figure with the one given in the question and obtain 3 linear equations in $x$,$y$ and $z$.

$$x+y=14$$

$$y+z=17$$

$$x+z=9$$
On solving, we get
$$\Rightarrow x=3$$

$$\Rightarrow y=11$$